# Cannot connect to remote computer on private network via PsExec

Tags: windows, remote-access, psexec

I have two computers connected to a router. Both have PsExec in sys32. Files and Printer sharing are enabled and firewall exception is disabled for PsExec.

On first computer in Command Prompt I ran:

```
psexec -u user \\192.168.1.4 cmd
```

After a while this shows up:

```
Couldn't access 192.168.1.4
Access denied
```

I confirmed that Domain\User is invalid. *user* is a Administrator on target machine.

**What is missing?**

**Edit:** First laptop is running Windows 7 and second is running Windows 8.

Comment: *user is a Administrator*...on 192.168.1.4, correct? This sounds like a firewall issue. Try temporarily disabling the firewall on 192.168.1.4.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the domain name to the user name: `-u domain\user`

Comment: @Twisty you are right! So what exact property on Firewall i need to do? I don't want to disable firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the machine you want to remotely access with PsExec, enable the following Inbound firewall rules in the predefined *File and Printer Sharing* group:

- NB-Datagram-In
- NB-Name-In
- NB-Session-In

[image]

With these rules enabled, users with Administrative permissions on the machine will be able to issue commands remotely via PsExec.